# what does " if (!((-s<filename/filepath>) && (some condition))) " in perl do?.

Tags: perl, scripting, perlscript

Hi I am a beginner at perl. I came across this statement and read some of the answers in Stackoverflow that said that it checks for non-zero file size. Pls explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation covers the `-s` operator, nothing more. It returns the file's size; if it is empty, the numeric zero is interpreted as false in boolean context, while any nonzero number is true.

```
print "has contents" if -s "/path/to/file";
```

The `!` is a negation, and `&&` is logical "and"; so the entire expression is true when either the file is empty or the other condition is false, or both. (Remember de Morgan's laws; *!(x&y)* is equivalent to *!x | !y*.)

Comment: -s will also return false (specifically, undef) if the file does not exist (or is a broken link)

Answer (score 0):

`-s` returns the size of a file. Zeros in perl are treated as falses (similar to like [c](/questions/tagged/c)). If you put this all together, it's a shorthand way checking that the given file is not empty.